# autofill using datagridview from another form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

hey guys i wanna make an auto fill using a datagridview from another form but the problem is i cant make the value to go back to previous form it just keep creating a new form.it works doe the data is being transfered  but in another new  form please help

```
    Dim form As New FormLibrarianMain

    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow
        row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

        form.Labelid.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        form.Labelfirstname.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        form.Labelmiddlename.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        form.Labellastname.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString()
        form.Labelgender.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString()
        form.Labeladdress.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value.ToString()
        form.Labelcity.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value.ToString()
        form.Labelpostcode.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value.ToString()
        form.Labelemail.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(8).Value.ToString()
        form.Labeldob.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(9).Value.ToString()

        form.Labeltype.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(10).Value.ToString()


        form.ShowDialog()
        Me.Hide()







    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: your question is not really clear. does your form keep creating form? or do you have a problem in filling datagridview?

Comment: "keeps creating form!"

Comment: Please post your full `Sub` then, on how you call it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data from one `Form` to other `Form`. you can create a `public` variable to store the `values`

```
Class Form2
   public values as New ArrayList

   Private Sub FormLoad(..)
     if values.Count >= 0 then
         TextBox1.Text = values(1)
         TextBox2.Text = values(2)
     End If
   End Sub
End Class
```

From the **Form1:**

```
If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow
    row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

    With Form2
       .values = New ArrayList
       .values(0) = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
       .values(1) = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
       .values(2) = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
       .values(3) = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString()
       ' etc'
       .ShowDialog()
    End With
    Me.Hide()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to out your form object in global varable of the form your are calling that new form from. Add something like this to your global variables

```
  private LibrarianFormLoaded as boolean = false
```

then in your sub

```
sub IJustClickedSomething (sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

if LibrarianFormLoaded = false then  form = New FormLibrarianMain : LibrarianFormLoaded=true

    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow
        row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

        form.Labelid.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        form.Labelfirstname.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        form.Labelmiddlename.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        form.Labellastname.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString()
        form.Labelgender.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString()
        form.Labeladdress.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value.ToString()
        form.Labelcity.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value.ToString()
        form.Labelpostcode.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value.ToString()
        form.Labelemail.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(8).Value.ToString()
        form.Labeldob.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(9).Value.ToString()

        form.Labeltype.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(10).Value.ToString()


        form.ShowDialog()
        Me.Hide()







    End If
```

Then if the form is really unloaded then add this code to get the form to reload

```
LibrarianFormLoaded = false
```

If you hide your librarianform instead of disposing it then you can read all the values of your controls since the form is just not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers But I already fix it.it was just a mistake sorry for the confusing questions. i forgot to give u guys the most important code though

Dim form as new Formsomething

well that was a mistake ..i just replace every form with the actual form and it worked fine..i'm just a beginner at  coding so i'm sorry and my mistake but still thanks for the answer